# Gridview edit from two tables

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I am trying to do an update in the gridview and all worked good until I included the 'serviceArea' which is from another table.

here is my query.

```
var result = from u in _db.tbl_Users
             where u.UserName.Contains(searchQuery)
                   && searchQuery.Length > 0
                   && u.Deleted == false
             select new
             {
                 u.UserName,
                 u.Email,
                 u.IsAdmin,
                 u.ServiceAreaId,
                 u.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea,
                 u.UserId,
             };

grd_User.DataSource = result;
grd_User.DataBind();
```

when i try an edit the databinding Error says no definition is found for serviceArea.

Can i do this somehow through the:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Val_ServiceArea" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceArea") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Any help would be good thank you.

Comment: Did your previous query return plain `User`s?

Comment: Yes the gridview works ok and when i select a row to edit I get the Error 'code'DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType9`5[[System.Int32,  does not contain a property with the name 'ServiceArea'.'code'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit data in a gridview you can't use anonymous types, because they are immutable. When you sent plain `User`s to the gridview you could modify the data, but now you can't. You'll have to create a class (call it DTO or view model) to hold the data you show in the gridview, so you can edit them.

This means that you also have to write the modified results back the original users when you commit the changes.

Comment: I am lost with your answer. But it all worked fine until i decided to include the u.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea, that is the only problem. If i include a ddl in the grid view that populates when the grid opens and use the selected value.? better idea?

Comment: OK, you probably should select one property of ServiceArea (e.g. `u.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea.code`) because ServiceArea is an object, not a primitive value. But still, you can't use an anonymous type if you want the data to be editable.